# Express path missing after refresh

Tags: node.js, express, node-sass

`/styles.css` goes missing after I do a page refresh.

Here's my `package.json` build script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "nodemon -e js,css,handlebars -i scss --watch app --exec babel-node app/app.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir -p dist && babel app -s -D -d dist",
    "serve": "node dist/app.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
```

The problem only exists in the `dist` version.
I run `npm run build`, then `npm run serve`.
What this does is build and copy every file to `/dist` folder.
App is served in `/dist/app.js`.

So `/styles.css` loads on initial load, but subsequent loads shows request is cancelled. Tried loading the site with a private window but the problem persists. It loads **only once** again, after reloading the server.

[screenshot of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TSKy.jpg)

Here's `app.js`:

```js
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import express from 'express'
import exphbs from 'express-handlebars'
import path from 'path'
import sassMiddleware from 'node-sass-middleware'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()

// Config
app.locals.config = require('./config.json')

// Views and handlebars view engine
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: 'app/views/layouts',
    helpers: {
        sitename: function () {
            return app.locals.config.sitename
        },
        ga: function () {
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
               ...
            }
        },
    },
})
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

// Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

// Sass middleware
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/scss'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    sourceMap: true,
}))

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// Routes
app.use(require('./routes/index.js'))

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening at port ${PORT}...`))
```

I load `/styles.css` with this in my view template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

### Update and solved:

I should had added that my folder structure looks like this:

```
/app
  - public/
    - css
    - js
    - scss
  - routes/
    - ...
  - views/
    - ...
```

Solved the problem by changing the the `src` path in views template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Had to add `prefix` to `node-sass-middleware` too for local development.

```
// Sass middleware
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/scss'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
    prefix: '/css',
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    sourceMap: true,
}))
```